# C# WebForms Swapping to Development environment problem

Tags: c#, .net, webforms

I am working with iFrame in webforms. However, I am getting a error like below:

[image]

I know how people solve it in .net core (like that in there : `<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />` ) but I couldn't find any kind of solution in webforms.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can certainly have some custom setting that tells you this is "development" or "some kind" of debug mode.

Then on page load you can do this:

```
 if ("some kind of development mode")
 {
    this.pshow.Attributes.Add("src", "/PDF/web/viewer.html?file=" + strFWebPath);

 }
 else
 {
    this.pshow.Attributes.Add("src", "whatever here for pduction or release");
  }
```